# Let $\mathbb{C} = {a+bi | a,b \in \mathbb{R}}$ be the set of complex numbers where $i^2 = -1$ . Show that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am weak at analysis, so please bear with me because I may not even understand your explanations. So can you try to put it in a basic version as you can. I have no idea where to start on this question but I do have some understanding on fields. Any guidance is appreciated !

Comment: Do you know the definitions of groups and rings?

Comment: @wgrenard I do not, I'm sorry.

Comment: You need to know what a ring is in order to know what a field is. So it is best you look these definitions up. Wgrenard's answer provides a good definition of a field though, so start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most fundamental way to prove this is to just verify that $\mathbb{C}$ satisfies all of the requirements for being a field. You'll need to show all of the following things hold in $\mathbb{C}$:

1. That $\mathbb{C}$ is closed under addition and multiplication.
2. That addition and multiplication are associative and commutative.
3. That there is an additive identity and multiplicative identity.
4. That every element of $\mathbb{C}$ has an additive inverse, and that every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse.
5. That the left and right distributive laws hold.

All of these requirements are equivalent to saying that $\mathbb{C}$ is an abelian group with respect to addition, that $\mathbb{C^*}$ (the set of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{C}$) is an abelian group with respect to multiplication, and that the distributive laws hold.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some understanding on fields, and hopefully rings, you may say there is a ring homomorphism:
\begin{align}
&\longrightarrow\mathbf C\\
P(X)&\longmapsto P(i)
\end{align}
which is surjective. Its kernel is the ideal generated by $X^2+1$. You can prove this ideal is maximal (which means $X^2+1$ is an irreducible polynomial), hence the quotient $\mathbf R[X]/(X^2+1)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf C$, is a field.